# adding in a ArrayList by casting an Object, from table of Objects, into double

Tags: object, arraylist, casting, double, addition

Why the cast `(double)` doesn't work ? I nead to add doubles to my ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;


public class Vecteur extends ArrayList implements Cloneable{
    int n;

    public Vecteur(int n, Object ... V){
        this.n=n;
        if(V.length>=n)
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                add((double)V[i]);
        else{
            for(int i=0; i<V.length; i++){
                if(i<n) add((double)V[i]);
                add(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you are not using generics?

You could try making your class header something like this:

```
public class Vecteur<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Cloneable {...
```

Then for your constructor:

```
public Vecteur(int n, T... V) {...
```

Which will apply the class generic type to the constructor. In this manner, you can remove the cast from your code as long as you instantiate your container with a syntax like this:

```
Vecteur<Double> v = new Vecteur<Double>();
```

If you need information on generics, check out the Wikipedia page:

[Generics in Java - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

EDIT/UPDATE:
Your error in the comment is definitely what I expected to see. You can use the `java.lang.Double` wrapper class with exception handling to disallow trying to add objects that aren't castable to `double`:

```java
try { add(Double.valueOf(V[i].toString()).doubleValue()); }
catch(NumberFormatException nfEx)
{ nfEx.printStackTrace(); }
```

If you don't use this type of handling you'll get `ClassCastException`s.

Comment: I'm using this manner (raw types) for a unique purpose : demonstrating in a next time the advantages  of generic types.

Comment: in this class, precisely in the first constructor, I'm using 'Object' as the list parameters type so I can reuse the method in an other constructor like : Vecteur(Vecteur v){ this(v.n, v.toArray()); }

Comment: In that case, you're probably running into a runtime ClassCastException or something similar. The only way that code will work at runtime is passing in an object or array of objects that is/are castable to double.  Can you please post any error output you've encountered, as well as the code you're using to instantiate the class?

Comment: here is the error message : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [D cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
 at Vecteur.<init>(Vecteur.java:16)
here is the line 16 : add((double)V[i]);